# PCIe байты в десятичной или двоичной?

Tags: железо

собственно сабж, к примеру 16гбайт/с может быть в двоичной?

Comment: Откуда вы взяли эту цифру ? В википедии написано, что у версии 4.0 скорость 16 ГТ/c гига-транзакций в секунду. и там же написана формула пересчета - умножение на 8/10. Т.е. порядка 12.8 Гига-БИТ. откуда вы взяли ГигаБАЙТ совершенно не ясно

Comment: Байты это байты, а система счисления - лишь способ их записи на бумаге, не более того.

Comment: @Mike Почитывал http://www.thg.ru/graphic/mify_o_proizvoditelnosti_videokart_part2/print.html потом в википелии на странице https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_пропускных_способностей_интерфейсов_передачи_данных в написано тоже что и в статье ~15.75 оказалось в отдельной статье pcie есть табличка скоростей, а в верху написано  Гб/c (10^9 бит/c)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов нет, http://pervosoft.com.ua/gb-to-mb.html

Comment: А теперь господа, минусики попрошу убрать)))

Comment: @АльбусПерсивальДамблдор Байт - 8 бит. Килобайт - 1024 байта и так далее. Если кто-то неправильно употребляет кратные единицы - на байтах это никак не отражается.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вы не поняли или плохо прочитали, кратко: 1кб = 1024 байт, 1мб = 1024*1024 = 1 048 576, 1гб = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1 073 741 824 байт. В двоичной байт получается 2^30, а в десятичной 10^9. Что-то ещё не понятно? p.s. 1 024 000 000 - это маркетологи придумали

Comment: @АльбусПерсивальДамблдор байт - 8 бит. И мне непонятно как он может быть двоичным или десятичным, а также почему вы упорно не видите разницы между байтом и кратными ему единицами.

Comment: Ну ок, там под Гб/с имеется ввиду гигабит а не гигабайт (по крайней мере специально же расшифровка есть 10^9 БИТ). А минусы думаю все таки потому, что скорость передачи или объемы информации никакого отношения к системам счисления не имеют. И уж точно к десятичной, с которой компьютеры вообще не работают

Comment: @Mike вы не поняли, ещё раз, есть такие плохие дядечки - маркетологи, так вот они скрестили двоичный гигабайт = 2^30 и десятичный гигабайт = 10^9 - и там и там байты. И у них получилось 1 024 000 000 и они это назвали полноценным гигабайтом. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Двоичные_приставки вот вам и системы счисления. Пожалуйста отпишитесь если поняли о чём я.

Comment: @АльбусПерсивальДамблдор Ну кто как посчитал приставки в названиях все таки не принято относить к системам счисления, по крайней мере это не очевидно. Так что если вопрос был именно об этом, это надо было вопрос писать более развернуто, лучше прямо с точными числами

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось в отдельной статье wiki pcie есть табличка скоростей, а в верху написано Гб/c (10^9 бит/c)